# How to fill datas from sp to Datagrid view in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I created a DataGridview and set Columns(including textcolumns,comboboxcolumns etc).
Then i created a table and created a stored procedure for getting the data from table.
I actually wants to get the data from stored procedure and fill the data grid view each and every columns which i have created.Please help me the best solution.

Comment: You are asking a general question. You have to specify the technology you are going to use to retrieve data from database to the vb code. You can use ADO.NET, Linq, Entity Framework, etj.
If you are more specific, we can give you some hints or some example of populating grids with data using VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ADO.NET this is one example of the many:

```
 Public Function FillDataSet(yourQuery As String, ByVal ParamArray para() As Object) As DataTable

     dim _transaction As SqlTransaction
     Dim _command As SqlCommand

    _command = New SqlCommand(yourQuery, yourConnection)

    _ds = New DataSet
    _sqlda = New SqlDataAdapter(_command )
    _command.Transaction = _transaction

    For i = 0 To para.Count - 1
        _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" & i, para(i))
    Next

    _sqlda.Fill(_ds)

   return _ds.tables(0)

 End Function
```

'call it

```
 DataGridview1.datasource = Nothing
 DataGridview1.datasource = FillDataSet(YourQuery,YourParam)
```